# Bivariate optimal density

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, nonlinear-optimization, optimal-control, optimal-transport

Consider any feasible $p:[0,1]^2\to [0,1]$ that allows discontinuities and the problem

$$\min_{p(.)} \int_0^1\int_0^1 p(x,y)^2 dF(x) dG(y)$$

s.t.  $$\int_0^1 p(x,y)dG(y)=k\phantom{0} for \phantom{0} a.e.\phantom{0} x\in [0,1]$$

where $F,G$ are distribution functions and $1/2<k<1$.

How could I solve the problem analytically?

Answer (score 1):

By your condition on $p(x,y)$, we see that $p(x,y)=p(y)$ a.e.. Hence you just need to find
$$ \min_p \int_0^1 p(y)^2 dG(y) $$
s.t.
$$ \int_0^1 p(y) dG(y) =k $$
To minimize the functional, we perform a variation according to Lagrange multipliers. Take $p \to p + h \xi$ then we see first order terms in $h$ correspond to
$$ \delta^{(1)} =\int_0^1 [2p(y)  - \lambda ]\xi(y) dG(y)$$
To get a critical point, we need $p(y)=\lambda/2$ a.e. since we need $\delta^{(1)} =0 $ for all test functions $\xi$. But the constraint gives us that the solution is
$$ p(x,y) = k \quad a.e. $$
For reference : [Calculus of variations: Lagrange multipliers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529416/calculus-of-variations-lagrange-multipliers)

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer. I think the constraint on the marginal does not imply p(x,y)=p(y) a.e.because there are other classes of  infinite many solutions satisfying the constraint but depend essentially on both x and y.

Comment: The example for the multiplicity of solutions is here :  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131684/finding-measure-given-constant-margins

Comment: @user91360 because you're minimizing p, if enough to show it in just x by your constraint...sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Could I modify the above reasoning by first considering the relaxed problem,

$$ \min_p \int_0^1\int_0^1 p(x,y)^2 dG(y)dF(x) $$
s.t.
$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 p(x,y) dG(y)dF(x) =k $$

Take $p \to p + h \xi$ then we see first order terms in $h$ correspond to
$$ \delta^{(1)} =\int_0^1 \int_0^1 [2p(x,y)  - \lambda ]\xi(x,y) dG(y)dF(x)$$
To get a critical point, we need $p(x,y)=\lambda/2$ a.e.  Then,

$$ p(x,y) = k \quad a.e. $$

Since the solution is also feasible for the unrelaxed problem, we conclude the solution to the original problem is also the constant.

Comment: This is exactly what I assumed....